# Categorical "scatter" plot with multiple variables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to prepare a "scatter" plot, as shown below, of say 5 variables (d1 to d5). The Y axis should be values of the variables (0-100%), with d1 to d5 adjacent to each other on the x axis so that we have 5 columns of points.

This needs to be repeated for 35 countries so that we can merge all 5-column plots on one or two A4 pages. So, in fact we have two type of categorization nested on the X axis: one for d1 to d5, and the second for names of countries.

[image: Sample Draw]

Comment: Are you asking how to make your idea in Excel? If yes, then please add some sample data (even hand drawing would be good). If you question is how your chart should look like, then it's not an Excel related question.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I need to know how to do it please. A draw added.

Comment: If you combine all into one graph, your vertical position (Y) is just a set of numbers to show row position could be your X axis and create a dummy set of number= 5*35 in increments of 1  so that the 1st country and delta 1 is the highest row or Y value then the x value is the % diff. and all the Y values for the 1st symbol  are included for each of 5 sets of data. ( your columns)   It gets confusing because we have transpose everything. X is horiz. Y is vert. FYI.   It would take a page of instructions, which is harder than doing it.

Answer (score 0):

all country data must be one data string for y.

To create this Y axis we need to create a column of integers in descending order from (35*(5+1space) 140 to 1. This is the value showing the position on the Y axis and is the same range of Y values for all 5 sets

The X axis is the % value of the each data set

Each vertical common symbol must be one data set for y 
all 5 data sets include every country A to Z

Lots of manipulation of graph  ( Open Office same as Excel)
[image]

Comment: Graph can be scaled but text box font must be scaled separately. It may fit on 2 pages or  depending on taste

Comment: that sounds a great approach. I know, as you mentioned, the instruction would be a page especially with manipulation needed. But, please how to get there? I am using Excel; the chart type should be scatter plot, which part of data you select initially? how to set Deltas and name of countries? in some bullet points if possible please.

Comment: free form text box was used for left side.  Y axis range is the same for all 5 sets, datasets are in rows, and X values are your % values in each column.   dataset name just point to headers one at a time, 1,2,3,4,5.  Hightlight data to include row header name and not column name (manual). the. go to it

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the delayed reply. I returned to this task after a while. It worked well. just i did not get your last comment fully, but sorted it somehow. Bests,

Comment: then problem solved

Comment: I was just reminding U that there are only 5 sets of data and how to start the graph process with an array to include xy headers or not. Because Y axis titles were manual free form text